# Нельзя изменять значение переменной цикла внутри этого цикла

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Здравствуйте. Извиняюсь, за возможно глупый вопрос, но я только начал изучать Паскаль и уже много, что перепробовал для исправления проблемы, но не вышло, поэтому решил обратиться сюда. У меня такая проблема: при запуске программы пишет ошибку в 19 строке:

> Нельзя изменять значение переменной цикла внутри этого цикла

А вот собственно сам код:

```
uses crt;
type
   Tmas=array[1..20] of real;
   Tmatr=array[1..20] of Tmas;
procedure Per(k,n:integer;var a:Tmatr; var b:Tmas);
var i,j:integer;z:real;
begin
   z:=a[k,k];i:=k;//если главный элемент строки (a[k,k])=0, z=0; запоминаем эту строку  
                                            ///(i:=k;) 
   for j:=k+1 to n do //от следующей стороки до конца ищем самый большой элемент в том столбце, где 0
     begin
       if abs(a[j,k])>z then //обычный поиск максимального
          begin
            z:=a[j,k];
            i:=j;
          end;
       if i>k then //если нашли больше ноля
          begin     
            for j:=k to n do //то делаем обмен элементами между строкой с нолем и            
               begin    //строкой с максимальным элементом в столбце с нолем
                 z:=a[i,j];a[i,j]:=a[k,j];a[k,j]:=z;
               end;
            z:=b[i];b[i]:=b[k];b[k]:=z; //обмениваем свободные члены
          end;
       end;
     end;
var a:Tmatr; //матрица системы
    b:Tmas;   //массив свободных членов
    x:Tmas;   //массив корней системы
    n,i,j,k:integer; //счетчики циклов
    z,r,g:real;  //вспомогательные переменные при расчетах
begin
clrscr;
write('Введите количество уравнений n=');
readln(n);
writeln('Введите коэффициенты системы и свободные члены');
for i:=1 to n do
for j:=1 to n+1 do
read(A[i,j]);  //вводим в строку через пробел коэффициенты и свободный член первого уравнения, жмем  
                    //Enter, 
                   //вводим следующую строку и так до конца
clrscr;     //очищаем экран
writeln('Матрица коэффициентов и свободных членов'); //выводим матрицу системы
for i:=1 to n do
  begin
    for j:=1 to n+1 do
    write(A[i,j]:6:2);
    writeln;
  end;
//Прямой ход Гаусса, преобразуем квадратную матрицу коэффициентов в треугольную типа
//2,35 -5,36 4,56 16,25
//0,00 -3,25 7,26 25,39
//0,00 0,00 2,35 59,23  //здесь потом найдем 3-ий корень (59,23/2,35), а от него обратным ходом остальные
for i:=1 to n do
b[i]:=a[i,n+1];  //присваиваем значения массиву свободных членов (последний столбец матрицы)
for k:=1 to n do  //начинаем с первой строки
     begin
       if a[k,k]=0 then Per(k,n,a,b);//добавлена процедура
       for j:=k+1 to n do //идем по строке выше главной диагонали до конца
          begin
            r:=a[j,k]/a[k,k]; //вычисляем коэффициент приведения первых коэффициентов, чтобы они были   
                                    //равны и при вычитании давали 0 (освобождаемся от очередного неизвестного), 
                                    //например    
                                    //1-е ур. 2х1+3х1-4х3=12
                                     //2-е ур -3х1+2х2+2х3=25
                                     //r= -3/2, тогда 2х1*-3/2=-3х1 
                                     //вычтем из ур.2-ур.1, х1 исчезнет 
           for i:=k to n do
               begin
                 a[j,i]:=a[j,i]-r*a[k,i]; //сейчас умножив все первое урававнение на -3/2,  вычитаем из первого  
              end;                         //уравнения второе      
           b[j]:=b[j]-r*b[k];             //и свободнгые члены
        end;
     end;
   //система будет 1.    2х1+3х1-4х3=12
   //                         2.   0х1+(2-(3*-3/2))х2 +(2+(4*-3/2)=25-12*(-3/2)
//Обратный ход Гаусса, находим корни
for k:=n downto 1 do //от последней строки к первой
     begin
       r:=0;
       for j:=k+1 to n do //в строке от главной диагонали вправо (где не ноли)
         begin
           g:=a[k,j]*x[j]; //умножаем коэффициенты на  известные уже корни
           r:=r+g;         //суммируем
         end;
      x[k]:=(b[k]-r)/a[k,k];  //из преобразованного прямым ходом свободного члена вычитаем полученную  
                                      //суммму и делим на первый коэффициент (который на главной диагонали)
     end;   
writeln('Корни системы:'); //выводим результат
for i:=1 to n do
write('x[',i,']=',x[i]:0:2,'   ');
readln;
end.
```

PascalABC.Net
Помогите пожалуйста исправить проблему или подскажите, что не так. **Заранее большое спасибо :)**

Comment: Цикл (строка 9) по зпеременной j.  Внутри этого цикла (в строке 19) Вы опять задаете цикл по переменной j. Ошибка налицо.

Comment: @vikttur , А как мне иначе записать это? Я вот думаю, что можно с помощью цикла while (в 19 строке), но не уверен, что это правильно

Comment: @vikttur , большое спасибо, помогло :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цикл (строка 9) по переменной *j*. Внутри этого цикла (в строке 19) Вы опять задаете цикл по переменной *j*. Ошибка налицо.

Задайте внутри цикла другую переменную, букв в алфавите достаточно )